# Как выводить количество имён?

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте!
Помогите пожалуйста, я новичок в программировании. Вот, не могу понять одну вещь: когда в пользователь несколько раз вводить имя на textBox dataGridView должен выводить не несколько раз строк, а количество имен которые были введены на той же строке. Не работает код. А как сделать. Заранее спасибо большое!

```
      List<User> usn = new List<User>();
        conn.Open();
            SqlCommand seldb = new SqlCommand("Select * from User where username="+textBox1.text, conn);
            seldb.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataReader read = seldb.ExecuteReader();
               int i=0;
            int j = 0; 
                while (read.Read() == true)
                {
                    User ia = new User();
                    ia.Name = read["name"].ToString();
                    usn.Add(ia);
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
                    {
                        ia.Count = i;

                    }
                    i++;
                }
             conn.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = usn;
```

Comment: Может проблема в запросе к БД? С помощью `Select *` вы получаете всю информацию о содержимом, попробуйте `Select Count(*)`

Comment: Во первых удалите строку seldb.ExecuteNonQuery(); она тут явно лишняя. Во вторых напишите по русски внятно, что вы хотите? Если вы плохо знаете русский, попросите кого нибудь помочь вам с описанием проблемы. В третьих, глядя на ваш код, я сразу могу сказать, что строка i++; должна быть в начале цикла, иначе Count у вас всегда будет на 1 меньше. В третьих само Count наверное означает не количество, а порядковый номер (именовать переменные надо правильно, чтобы ваш код был понятен не только вам). В четвертых я совсем не понял, что вы хотели сказать вашим условием if